# Alternative to assert to get failures log message and continue?

Tags: java, junit4

I'm new into JUnit4, and I am used to Google Test for C++. I wrote a piece of code with many checks using `assertEquals()`. I thought it would output some log information to tell the user if a check has been successful or not and why, and continue with the next `assertEquals()`. But it is stopping the execution right there.

I have searched about this topic, and it seems like JUnit is designed different from Google Test, so I should use a @Test method for each assert. But is there any alternative to get what I want? I read about verify method instead of assert, but it was related to Selenium, which I don't even know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ErrorCollector](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) rule to do multiple asserts.

```
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

@Test
public void testMethod()
{
   collector.checkThat(variable, equalTo(otherVaiable));
   collector.checkThat(variable2, equalTo(otherVaiable2));
}
```

The checkThat method uses hamcrest matchers to do the asserting.

Comment: Looks like the solution I am looking for. But still have one problem: it doens't recognise the method equalTo. I have searched at JUnit API and found that checkThat second argument must be a Matcher<T> object, but I haven't been able to find information about which Matchers are available

Comment: @RomanRdgz equalsTo is a static method in org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers

Answer (score 2):

Your research is pretty much correct. Purists believe you should have exactly one assertion in each test case. I don't follow that rule, but interrupting the test as soon as first assertion fails<sup>1</sup> is a good idea.

Consider the following example:

```
assertEquals(1, listOfNames.size());
assertEquals(10, listOfNames.get(0).length());
```

Running the second assertion if the first one fails doesn't make much sense. Cascading failures won't help you in finding the root cause.

<sup>1</sup> - in fact, special exception is thrown when assertion fails